# Why do rubber duck antennas have this metal part, while other antennas do not?

Tags: rf, antenna, radio

If you open up a rubber duck antenna, it usually has a wire inside, plus a crimped on piece of metal, like this:
[image: antenna1]
[image]

Other antennas, like those on an RC receiver do not have this second metal part:
[image: antenna2]

Both of these antennas are 2.4ghz, why does one require this metal part where the other does not?

Also, if the metal tube forms part of a dipole, then how is it electrically different than the shield it's covering? I think they're connected. Wouldn't it do nothing that the shield isn't already doing?

Comment: A rubber duck cannot form a dipole. It can form a monopole.

Answer (score 2):

The cutaway picture looks like a coaxial sleeve antenna.  [Section 3](http://www.ece.mcmaster.ca/faculty/nikolova/antenna_dload/current_lectures/L11_Match.pdf) in the linked reference discusses this type of antenna.
edit: also see figure `a` on page 11 (assymetrically-fed sleeve dipole)

Comment: Nice reference.

Comment: That helps, but what I really want to know is what practical difference this makes.

Answer (score 0):

I found a source, that seems to answer my question.

https://www.rchelicopterfun.com/rc-antenna.html

The "whisker" type antenna is a linear monopole.
The sleeved antenna is an "assymetrically-fed sleeve dipole" (as AlmostDone pointed out).

According to the link:

> Since the transmitter is transmitting the RF as a sinusoidal wave, it needs both poles as it alternates between positive and negative voltage for improved efficiency. If the transmitter only had a monopole, roughly half the power would be transmitted. Lost efficiency...

This is the "practical" answer that I was looking for (if it's correct).